# Tomcat - do things after response

Tags: java, android, tomcat, httpresponse

I have a servlet for the purposes of uploading my application's database in android.

The database is processed on the server side but that could take a while.

At the moment, I'm just returning back with a response that the upload has been successful using PrintWriter.write().

Is there a way after the response has been sent to the client(my android app) to start processing the file?

If I send a redirect to another servlet or forward the request using the dispatcher, I won't have a response until the servlet that carries out the processing is finished.

What's the best way, to respond to the user instantly,let the processing of the database begin and send the results back to android (note this could take 5 minutes or 10 minutes, depending on the database - so I'm assuming I would need some sort of listener to poll on the server whether the results have been processed and ready to be shown on the client)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backend processing can be done via a job, e.g. via Quartz. If the server could be replaced with JBoss AS, Glassfish or Resin, a simple @Asynchronous annotated method could also do the job here.

You can indeed poll the server continuously to ask if it's already done. This is what the majority of the AJAX based progress bars in a web environment also do.

Alternatively you could make use of reverse AJAX (Comet) to prevent the polling (see e.g. http://atmosphere.java.net/). In that case the server is able to push a response back to you as soon as it's done. This does necessitate some kind of eventing on your server. If you could replace the server with JBoss AS or Glassfish, the CDI event bus could be an option. Otherwise, a shared object in the HTTP session on which you call wait/notify is a crude alternative.

Comment: so tomcat is out of the question for what Im trying to do?

Comment: Not at all! But Tomcat is just very bare bones. It implements Servlet and JSP and very little else. Additional functionality can be added, but you have to do that yourself. Those other servers I mentioned already have that functionality.

Comment: since this is just for my individual project, nothing to do with production-ready stuff, I ll give JBoss a go, since that's the one you said first in the list unless u recommend otherwise.

Comment: Agreed. An EJB with an @Asynchronous method is the way to go. Make sure you get the latest version of JBoss. It implements the EJB 3.1 specification, which is *much* more user-friendly than the previous ones.

Comment: @arjan is tehre an example u can refer me to with JBoss/Servlet and Quartz job?

Comment: Using JBoss AS 6 you don't need Quartz. See this for a simple example of a bean with an asynchronous method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288098/how-to-send-email-in-java-using-asynchronous-api/5289503#5289503 You can inject this bean into your servlet using the @EJB annotation.