# Java EE 6 sending email asynchronously JMS or asynchronous annotation

Tags: jms, java-ee-6

I want to write a web application, wherein I want to send emails asynchronously.

I am planning to use JMS queue to put the request to send the emails.
The consumer will pick the messages and call the APIs to send the emails.

Another option is to use @Asynchronous annotation for sending the emails.

Which is a better option?

Answer (score 1):

The SMTP server will have a queuing mechanism purpose-built for delivering email.  Unless you need some particular feature of JMS, I would just use @Asynchronous.  Otherwise, you're reinventing the wheel and potentially adding bugs to the process.

Answer (score 0):

Unless and untill you are having a specific bean implementing the email logic don't use JMS queues to send emails asynchronously. Instead using @Asynchronous is a good option or implement the email logic in a new thread.

Refer to this post for more details

[How to send email in java using asynchronous API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288098/how-to-send-email-in-java-using-asynchronous-api)